# have java open an oft then attach a file

Tags: java

I have been trying to read as much on stackoverflow about this as possible, but I need to open an outlook offline template (.oft) file. Then have a file attached to it. I will put the command into a java application.

I would use a command line switch, but it creates a new message with the attachment and opens the oft file, it's not attaching it to the .oft.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Outlook.exe" /f "C:\RSASoftToken\android.msg" /a "C:\RSASoftToken\android\WMH7.sdtid"
```

If there is a way to get command line to work, that would be the easiest. If not what else can I do in java?

I need to add it to this code

```
    //the New File Name
    String newFileName = Prefix + fileName.substring(0,4) + Suffix + fileExtension;
    String tentativeName = "new Filename will be ->"+newFileName+"\n";
    System.out.println(tentativeName);
    if(cbxAndroid.isSelected() == true ){
        try {   Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();                               
                Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c \\RSASoftToken\\TokenConverter.exe \\RSASoftToken\\android\\"+newFileName+" -android -o \\RSASoftToken\\android\\"+newFileName.substring(0,4)+".txt");
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));                  
                String line=null;                 
        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {                     
            System.out.println(line);                 }                  
        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();                 
        System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);              
        } catch(Exception e) {                 
            System.out.println(e.toString());                 
            e.printStackTrace();             
            }         

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you would execute that command from Java:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Outlook.exe",
        "/f",
        "C:\mail\android.oft",
        "/a",
        "C:\android\file.txt");
```

You can then call the `getXxxStream()` methods on the `Process` object to get streams for writing to the external processes standard input and reading from its standard output and standard error.

However, I don't understand what you are really trying to do here, or whether running this command will allow you to achieve it.

Comment: how would i make that work with this code, udpated to the above

Comment: so it opens the oft file and opens a new email with the file attached, it's not attaching the file to the oft. my oft is html and the new email created is html. this needs to work on outlook 2010 and win 7 64bit.

Comment: This is beyond my understanding / experience.  I don't even understand the terminology you are using.  Sorry.  Perhaps you should change the tags to something more appropriate.  It is no longer a plain Java problem.